# StAX Parser (parser.next)?

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I have started learning about operating XML files in JAVA.
I've tried a basic StAX parser and I've stucked with parser.next().
Why parser.next()? The reason of it is that I can't return the value from method parser.next(). The connection is opened and when you put parser.next() method to basic output in order to test it, it won't return anything, even 0. So, could you help with that problem. I was looking for the solution before, but I didn't find anything helpful. Thanks in advance.
Example code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    String urlString = "";
    if(args.length == 0)
    {
        urlString = "http://www.w3c.org";
        System.out.println("Using: " + urlString);
    }
    else urlString = args[0];
    URL url = new URL(urlString);
    InputStream in = url.openStream();
    XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
    XMLStreamReader parser = factory.createXMLStreamReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    while(parser.hasNext()){
        //System.out.println("test");
        int event = parser.next();
        System.out.println(parser.next() + "");
        if(event == XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT)
            if(parser.getLocalName().equalsIgnoreCase("a"))
            {
                String href = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "href");
                if(href != null) System.out.println(href);
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Start with a tutorial like https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/stax/example.html#bnbfo, then adapt it to your needs.

Comment: Okey, Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just in case. I've alread manage with that problem. Thanks anyway.